# Question about a created problem by me

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

If I created a problem (inequality), can I post the question here to see how other solutions can I receive? Or if the problem is too easy?

Thanks!

Comment: If you browse a little through meta, you can find some related discussions (although probably not exactly the same). For example, these posts (and other posts linked there) seem somewhat related to me: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8424/questions-that-ask-to-verify-solution-to-problem and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9362/posting-questions-you-already-know-how-to-answer